# How to find parent comit when merge conflict occur?

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

Time to time I get merge conflicts:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD

    $ENV{CONFIG_DIR} = lib::abs::path('../config');
||||||| parent of 89a6bb1f37 (Dump info about directories)
    $ENV{CONFIG_DIR}
        = lib::abs::path('../../config');
=======
    my $path = $ENV{CONFIG_DIR}
        = lib::abs::path('../../config');
    say "Live configuration path is: $path";

    return $path;
>>>>>>> 89a6bb1f37 (Dump info about directories)
```

I can view commit which introduced changes from `parent` to `current`:
`git show 89a6bb1f37`

Curious to know how to find commit which introduced changes from `parent` to `HEAD`.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD

    $ENV{CONFIG_DIR} = lib::abs::path('../config');
||||||| parent of 89a6bb1f37 (Dump info about directories)
    $ENV{CONFIG_DIR}
        = lib::abs::path('../../config');
=======
```

Comment: `HEAD` points (ultimately, even if it points to a branch) to a commit. `git show HEAD` (or simply `git show`) will output the diff between that commit and **its** parent. If you want to see the diff between `HEAD` and the merge-base (in your conflict), you have it here above the `=======` line. What exactly do you call `parent` here? Your `git show 89a6bb1f37` showed you the diff between `89a6bb1f37` and **its** parent.

Comment: @RomainValeri: No `git show HEAD` will show HEAD commit, and not that one which introduce change. 2. I call `parent`: the next thing `parent of 89a6bb1f37`

Comment: @RomainValeri is correct; your terminology is nonstandard and I think it is likely that nobody but you will understand you if you continue to use it that way. There are sometimes reasons to fight against Git's terminology (it's often confusing), but parent/child are pretty well-defined here in tree and graph informatics usage.

Answer (score 0):

I can use `git follow`:

```
git follow <path to file> <line N from> <line N to>
```

Add alias into `.gitconfig`

```
    # Follow evolution of certain lines in a file
    # arg1=file, arg2=first line, arg3=last line or blank for just the first line
    # arg4=commit from which we want to see history. Useful when code is moved or file was removed
    # bash_fn = "!bash -c 'f(){ echo $1; };f $@' --"
    follow = "!bash -c '                                                 \
        if [[ $1 == \"/\"* ]]; then                                      \
            FILE=$1;                                                     \
        else                                                             \
            FILE=${GIT_PREFIX}$1;                                        \
        fi;                                                              \
        echo \"git log --topo-order -u -L $2,${3:-$2}:\\\"$FILE\\\" $4 \";   \
        git log -w -b -p --ignore-blank-lines --topo-order -u -L $2,${3:-$2}:\"$FILE\" $4;\
    ' --"
```

Comment: `git follow` produces `git: 'follow' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.` Your `git-follow` must be your own invention (or some script you imported from somewhere); it's not clear where you got it.

Comment: This does seem like a useful script / command, though, so you might want to find out where it came from and mention that, in your answer, so that other people can find and use it.

Comment: @torek: Yes, sorry about that. I added the alias.